# How to connect to LinkedIn

Tags: social-media

I want to draw a graph of a network of LinkedIn users/followers/companies, etc., using LinkedIn data.

I tried this:

```
SocialMediaData["LinkedIn", "Connections"]
```

but the output was a login window (which credentials should I use?) and the following message:

```
OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication::reqbdy: The service LinkedIn returned invalid request token response oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_problem_advice=javax.security.auth.login.LoginException%20while%20obtaining%20request%20token%20for%20%3AGET%26https%253A%252F%252Fa\[Ellipsis] _basicprofile%252520r_fullprofile%252520r_emailaddress%252520r_network%252520r_contactinfo%252520rw_nus%252520rw_groups%0AConsumer%20key%20%205a1p1bg1re1i%20is%20disabled.
```

Thanks for your help!